# How can I open an unsynced file from OneDrive?

Tags: vdi

I cannot open this unsynced file from one drive. How do I open this file? This is from my VDI, this file was unsynced from my VDI, now I cannot open this file. I have tried the steps from microsoft documentation, it didn't help